# Android Studio sqlite Codes too large

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite codes that worked until i reached 10,000 lines. Then it won't let me run the app. The error says "codes too large". I understand that it has a limit, I've googled it it says something about the 64k limit? Some suggest that i try importing it using text files, i have no idea how to do that. what should i do? please help :(

Here are my codes, 10,000 codes like that:

```
_db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (Desc, num, qty, book)" + " VALUES ('sample', 2, 25, 'Book1');");
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you have 10,000 lines of _db.exeSQL()?

Comment: Yes sir, i have 30,000 records that i want to insert in my sqlitedb

Comment: Then try to create a function which takes a String, and pass " VALUES ('sample', 2, 25, 'Book1');") as String.

Comment: Please tell me how to do it